# stackoverflow exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-overflow, runtime-error

In the code below it should multiply 2 numbers. It works for 3 and less than 3 digits numbers but when I give numbers with 4 digits or bigger it gives runtime error: `stackoverflow exception was unhandled`. I've commented where the problem is. I thought the problem is for defining variables in `int` and changed them in long but the problem still exists. Where is the mistake?

**edited:**
now,whats do you think about the problem?it doesnt do anything

```
        public long Prod2(long u, long v)
    {
        var numbers = textBox7.Text.Split(',').Select(p => long.Parse(p)).ToArray();
        int n = Math.Max((int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(u) + 1),(int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(v) + 1));        
        int threshold = 3;

        if (u == 0 || v == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (n <= threshold)
        {
            return u * v;
        }
        else
        {
            int m = (int)Math.Ceiling(n / 2.0);

            int x = (int)(u / Math.Pow(10, m));
            int y = (int)(u % Math.Pow(10, m));
            int w = (int)(u / Math.Pow(10, m));
            int z = (int)(v % Math.Pow(10, m));

            long r = Prod2(x + y, w + z);
            long p = Prod2(x, w);
            long q = Prod2(y, z);

            return p * (long)Math.Pow(10, 2 * m) + (r - p - q) * (long)Math.Pow(10, m) + q;
            long result = Prod2(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
            textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @arash - I'd be glad to help if you could explain *what* exactly this method is trying to *do*?

Comment: m is a 3-digit number???

Comment: The stackoverflow exception is not caused by arithmetic operation. It is because your recursion does not stop for some reason.

Comment: thanks sir,it multiply two numbers,user write two numbers in textbox7 and then it multiply the numbers,for 3 and less than 3 digits it does general multiply,and for bigger than 4 digits it get the maximum digits of input numbers(n),and.....where of my explain isnt complete?say me to explain again

Comment: @arash - Ok I understand the first part (multiply two numbers when # of digits is <= 3). Otherwise, just get the larger of the two numbers' digits?

Comment: no,it gets the larger of two numbers digits and then divide 2 and put it in m and then u divide 10^m andy and w and z do like that.the in bigzarb(x,w) it  replace u with x and v with w and multiply 10^m and again bigzarb(x,z)+bigzarb(w,y).....

Comment: @arash - Ok, I understand *the code*, but *what* are you trying to do. *What* is this program *doing*, not the *code* because I can read that.

Comment: i want to multiply numbers with this way in this algorithm

Comment: Ok, but *what* is the algorithm. Does it have a name? Is it some financial calculation? I will gladly rewrite the method for you in a much more proper format if I can just *understand* what you're trying to do.

Comment: unfortunately i cant find any sample of it in internet,we have it in our foundation of algorithms book

Comment: @arash, Can you submit your formula here, so we can guide you in better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I've completely translated the algorithm described in the book for you:

```
public long Prod2(long u, long v)
{
    int n = Math.Max((int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(u) + 1), (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(v) + 1));
    int threshold = 3;

    if(u == 0 || v == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n <= threshold)
    {
        return u * v;
    }
    else
    {
        int m = (int)Math.Ceiling(n / 2.0);

        int x = (int)(u / Math.Pow(10, m));
        int y = (int)(u % Math.Pow(10, m));
        int w = (int)(u / Math.Pow(10, m));
        int z = (int)(v % Math.Pow(10, m));

        long r = Prod2(x + y, w + z);
        long p = Prod2(x, w);
        long q = Prod2(y, z);

        return p * (long)Math.Pow(10, 2 * m) + (r - p - q) * (long)Math.Pow(10, m) + q;
    }
}
```

To get the right result, you'd call this method from some *other* method like this:

```
void Main()
{

    // Call the method and store the result in variable 'r'.
    long r = Prod2(1234, 5678);
    Console.WriteLine(r);

    /////////////////////////////////
    //
    // OR - In your case read from textBox7 and then store the result in textBox1    
    //
    /////////////////////////////////
    var numbers = textBox7.Text.Split(',').Select(p => long.Parse(p)).ToArray();
    long result = prod2(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

So in your event handler, for example for `button1`, you'd do *this* to make the call:

```
public void button1_Click()
{
    var numbers = textBox7.Text.Split(',').Select(p => long.Parse(p)).ToArray();
    long result = prod2(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Don't modify the `Prod2` that I have, and just paste it with your code. This way, Prod2 does the calculation and then your `button1_Click` controls the *input* and what to do with the *output*.

Comment: thanks,but it with each numbers i entere,it says less than 3 digits:2

Comment: @arash - Well yeah - I put those there so you could see the recursion happening. Remove or comment out any `Console.WriteLine` or `MessageBox.Show` lines so that it *doesn't* have the output.

Comment: ok,and when it doesnt give output what can i do with this code?

Comment: What do you mean? It does give the output. When you `return result` that gives the result back to the method that *called* `bigzarb()`.

Comment: thanks but i dont know why i dont understand,does your code work the same of my code?

Comment: thanks so much,but it is different from my code,your code just output:less than 3 digits:2,but mine should multiply two numbers

Comment: @arash - No, my code *returns* the value (look at the *return* statement). You can always replace `Console.WriteLine` with the `textBox7.Text = result;` or something like that. I think you're misunderstanding some fundamentals for programming and C#.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky :i edited my question with your code,can you help me more?thanks so much

Comment: @arash - Can you maybe take a picture of the formula/algorithm in the textbook and then upload it here? It would really help.

Comment: thanks for your helps,i found that finally in google book,see this page please,page 74    http://books.google.com/books?id=vQpkQFG2Wn4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=richard+neapolitan+foundation+of+algorithm&source=bl&ots=vaJqMNIUr_&sig=-IHD6aYric5QkhkoVN_EuxFg8ys&hl=en&ei=-L8QTaKDBYeh8QO0xcGEBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @arash - Google books doesn't have those specific pages listed. Do you have another source?

Comment: i found that and uploaded the file,its format is docx,http://www.upcenter.ir/uploads/1344379804.zip

Comment: @arash - Thanks for that. I've updated my post. This should work for you if you understand how to use it. If this works, please mark this answer as the answer.

Comment: i edited my question sir,what do you think now?thanks so so much,i dont know how should i gratify your helps

Comment: @arash - Where are you calling this method from? See my edit above.

Comment: wowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww,finally it work,it was the best  memory of writing code.you did perfect,thanks so so much

Answer (score 3):

You are getting into an infinite recursive loop at this point

```
 long result = bigzarb(x, w) * Math.Pow(10, m) + (bigzarb(x, w) + bigzarb(w, y)) * Math.Pow(10, m) + bigzarb(y, z);///here
    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

I notice this line is executed only when `intn > 3`, so perhaps you have a logic bug there?

**Update:** After reading your comments I can see that this test is intended to say "if the length of this string is <= 3 then..."  when in fact as written it is actually saying "if the VALUE of this converted string is <= 3 then..."

Comment: what should i do to stop the loop when it runs 1time

Comment: @Saeed The reported error is StackoverflowException not OverflowException, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx

Comment: @Ed Guiness:what should i do to stop the loop when it runs 1time?thanks

Comment: @arash Guessing this is homework on recursion - take heart...many struggle to grasp this first time.  Suggest trying to draw a flow-chart of the logic and using better-named variables.  Also see my comments on @annakata's answer

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell you have a potential (varying on input) case of:

```
function bigzarb()
{
    bigzarb()
}
```

so long as the numbers in `textBox7` are > 3, i.e. an unclosed recursion loop, which will inevitably become a stackoverflow.

Put a breakpoint on the line in question and you'll quickly see the problem. Without knowing what your method does (I don't recognise the algorithm) I can't help much about cleaning it up, but the first step might be to have a get out clause to return from the function conditionally. However, I also see you overwriting the input arguments `u` and `v` before they get used so perhaps you've made a mistake in the algo?

Comment: ++ this is the right answer, see also my answer for the specific line

Comment: thanks sir,it multiply two numbers,user write two numbers in textbox7 and then it multiply the numbers,for 3 and less than 3 digits it does general multiply,and for bigger than 4 digits it get the maximum digits of input numbers(n),and then divide 2 and put it in m and then u divide 10^m andy and w and z do like that.the in bigzarb(x,w) it replace u with x and v with w and multiply 10^m and again bigzarb(x,z)+bigzarb(w,y)...

Comment: @arash whoa, slow down... first thing, when you say "less than 3 digits" please look again at these lines...   int intn = Convert.ToInt32(n); if (intn <= 3)... this is not "how many digits", but rather "is this number less than or equal to 3" (in value not length)

Answer (score 0):

Pow method returns double, so I think your x, y, z, w, and z should be declared as double as well.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting "StackoverFlow" for the Recursive call. its better to mold the holes found in the code. I suggest you to change the logic.

static int callStack = 0;

```
    public double bigzarb(long u, long v)
    {
        callStack++;
         ............
         ............
```